# Register DLL with spaces in folder name

Tags: windows-7

I am trying to register dll in windows 7 from run menu with Regsvr32  C:\VS  Projects\Regerence\ checkscenter3des.dll. I am not able to register it because there is a space in folder name.

Answer (score 4):

Put double quotes around the DLL name:

```
Regsvr32 "C:\VS Projects\Regerence\checkscenter3des.dll"
```

Comment: I'm not sure what is wrong, but the command syntax is correct, maybe post that as another question?

Comment: It's probably a 32 bit DLL. Do it with 32 bit regsv32, `C:\Windows\SysWow64\regsvr32`

Comment: I don't think its 32 bit issue It says MOdule ""C:/VS" failed to load so it's a space issue

Comment: It works for me... I don't have the DLL but it says that the DLL in that full path is missing.

Comment: I just changed the folder name without space and now everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Consider including whole the path into "":

Regsvr32 "C:\VS Projects\Regerence\ checkscenter3des.dll"

Enjoy

Comment: I did that but did not work, I just changed the folder name without space and now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes and double escape character  Regsvr32 "C:\\VS Projects\\Regerence\\checkscenter3des.dll"

Answer (score -1):

I just changed the folder name without space and now everything works fine.